# Splitting a Time into Twelve Equal Parts

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get value of 12 equal parts of the night length.

This is what my table looks like:

```
sunrise_time             sunset_time              Day_Length        Night_length
2014-01-01 06:02:41.000  2014-01-01 20:44:05.000  14:41:24.0000000  09:18:36.0000000
```

This is my query, but getting `day_length` instead of `night_light`:

```
select (convert(varchar(10),dateadd(ss,abs(datediff(ss,sunrise_time,sunset_time))/12,0),8)) as nighthour
from table1
```

Expected output: `00:46:33`

Actual output: `01:13:27`

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your start date and end date around in the `datediff` to avoid issues. Here's a small change to your code.

```
select convert(varchar(10), dateadd(ss, datediff(ss, 0, night_length) / 12, 0), 8)
from table1
```